# setting js azure app service custom login authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, azure, authentication

I started implementing 2 years ago my custom authentication in azure mobile service with node.js to use it in my jquery/cordova appery.io app. I have a database with users, passwords, etc and a login api in node.js backend that generates a valid jwt like this:

http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Exploring_custom_identity_in_Mobile_Services_Day_12_.aspx

http://chrisrisner.com/Version-1-of-the-Mobile-Services-JWT-token-has-been-deprecated

But now i have been migrated to azure app service and don´t know how to implement custom authetication with javascript.

At the examples above:

*"iss":"urn:microsoft:windows-azure:zumo",
"ver":2,
"aud":aud,*

But i have read that "aud" and "iss" must be my azure website and "sub" my own userId, to generate a valid jwt in my custom auth to use it in azure. Is it right?

https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/08/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-5-custom-authentication/

*The important thing is the token. There are some requirements for using 3rd party tokens with an Azure Mobile App:
    It must follow the Json Web Token format
    The user Id must be in the subject (sub) field
    The audience (aud) and issuer (iss) must be known and configured*

I do a call to my login API with ajax post and obtain a valid JWT token (http://jwt.io), but i don´t know the correct process to login and use azure services because i don´t know the correct way to use it on my app. I have changed MobileServices.Web.min.js to azure-mobile-apps-client.js in the app.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client

Can i use the jwt token created in azure node.js or exchange it for a session token and use client.login() method by JS SDK?

EDIT:
I see the light again adding to ajax POST
            `headers: {'X-ZUMO-AUTH': usuarioToken},`

So my "authenticated users only" api works again with the old MobileServices.Web.min.js! It also works perfect with invokeApi method:

```
var mobileClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(urlApp,keyApp);
mobileClient.currentUser = {
    userId: myCustomUserId,
    mobileServiceAuthenticationToken: myCustomToken
};
mobileClient
    .invokeApi('data', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'X-ZUMO-AUTH': myCustomToken},
            body: JSON.stringify(theData)
        }) //end invokeApi
    .done(
        function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("error"));
        }
    ); //end done
```

The mobileClient generated contains this data:

```
mobileClient= {"applicationUrl":"https://xxx.azure-mobile.net/","applicationKey":"hGhzxxx","version":"ZUMO/1.2 (lang=Web; os=--; os_version=--; arch=--; version=1.2.21003.0)","currentUser":{"userId":"Custom:25F600BB-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8329BCCF31D2","mobileServiceAuthenticationToken":"ey__rest of jwt token"},"_serviceFilter":null,"_login":{"_loginState":{"inProcess":false,"cancelCallback":null},"ignoreFilters":true},"push":{"_apns":null,"_gcm":null,"_registrationManager":null}}
```

I will try again wiht the new azure-mobile-apps-client.js
Any comment will be welcome

Comment: To confirm, are you using [Azure Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/) or [Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/)?

Comment: Hi Aaron! I use Azure Mobile Apps migrated from Azure Mobile Service. I had no time jet to try again azure-mobile-apps-client.js. with my app at https://appery.io . I can select cordova 3.7, 4.1 and 5.2 (for android) to make tests with my app in appery. Thank you.